# Exercise: Eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra

I have an exercise and I am trying to understand the solution. Many steps I do not understand. I am going to ask the questions below in the text with italic font.

**Exercise**

Consider the homogeneous $ 2 \times 2 $ system
$$ \dot x = Ax $$
where the distinct, real eigenvalues of $A$ are $λ_1$ and $λ_2$ with corresponding eigenvectors $t_1$ and $t_2$.

a) Using the Laplace transform
$$ sX(s) - x(0) = AX(s) $$
show that 
$$ X(s) = T  
        \begin{bmatrix}
        \frac{1}{s-\lambda_1} & 0 \\
        0 & \frac{1}{s-\lambda_2} \\
        \end{bmatrix} 
        T^{-1}x(0), ~~~~ T=\begin{bmatrix} t_1 & t_2 \end{bmatrix}
$$
where $ t_i$ are the columns of T.

b) Show that with the initial condition
$$ x(0) = kt_1$$
we have
$$X(s)= \frac{k}{s-\lambda_1}t_1 $$

c) For
$$ A=  
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 1 \\
-2 & -4
\end{bmatrix}$$
and with the initial condition
$$ x(0) =   \begin{bmatrix} -1 \\3 \end{bmatrix} $$
use the result of part (b) to derive $x(t)$ analytically. Then, by using MATLAB, plot
the behaviour of the system in a phase plane diagram (i.e. sketch $x_2(t)$ over $x_1(t)$ as t goes from zero to infinity).

**Solution**

a) By eigenvalue decomposition
$$ A=T\Lambda T^{-1}, ~~~~ T=\begin{bmatrix} t_1 & t_2 \end{bmatrix}, ~~~~ \Lambda=\begin{bmatrix} \lambda_1 & 0 \\ 0 & t_2 \end{bmatrix}$$

so
$$(sI-A)X(s) = x(0), ~~~~T(sI-\Lambda)T^{-1}X(s)=x(0) \\
X(s) = T (sI- \Lambda)^{-1}T^{-1}x(0) 
= T  
  \begin{bmatrix}
  \frac{1}{s-\lambda_1} & 0 \\
  0 & \frac{1}{s-\lambda_2} \\
  \end{bmatrix} 
  T^{-1}x(0)  $$
It is worthy to observe that we could not investigate the dynamic of a system with
its transfer function when it is affected only by some non-zero initial condition,
while this possibility is provided by state space model.

b) With initial conditions $ x(0) = kt_1 $ we have
$$ T^{-1}x(0) =\begin{bmatrix} k \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} ~~~~~ (T^{-1} \begin{bmatrix} t_1 & t_2 \end{bmatrix} = I \Rightarrow \begin{bmatrix} T^{-1}t_1 & T^{-1}t_2  \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$
$$ X(s) = k\begin{bmatrix} t_1 & t_2 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{s-\lambda_1} \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} = k \frac{1}{s-\lambda_1}t_1 $$

The solution is in the direction $ t_1 $ and only depends on $ \lambda_1 $.

c) From the result of part (b) for any initial condition of the form $x(0) = k_1 t_1 + k_2 t_2 $, the solution $x$ in frequency domain is
$$ X(s) = \frac{k_1}{s-\lambda_1}t_1 + \frac{k_2}{s-\lambda_2}t_2$$
and in time domain
$$ x(t) = k_1 e^{\lambda t}t_1 + K_2 e^{\lambda_2 t}t_2$$
By eigenvalue decomposition of $A$ with Matlab command eig, we obtain 
$$ \begin{bmatrix} t_1 & t_2 \end{bmatrix}  = \begin{bmatrix} 0.7071 & -0.4472 \\ -0.7071 & 0.8944 \end{bmatrix}, ~~~~ \lambda_1 =-2,~ \lambda_2 = -3 $$

We choose eigenvectors in a way to have $ \begin{bmatrix} t_1 & t_2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ -1 & 2 \end{bmatrix} $; note that the eigenvectors are not unique and only their directions matter.

As $t_1$ and $t_2$ are linearly independent, any arbitrary vector like $ x(0) = \begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix} $, can be written as linear combination fof $t_1$ and $t_2$. It is straightforward to calculate $k_1 = 1 $ and $k_2=2$ so that we have $ x(0) = t_1 + 2 t_2 $ and the solution is
$$ x(t) = e^{-2t} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix} + 2 e^{-3t} \begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}  $$

**Questions**

a) Why is the Λ enclosed by $T$ and $T^{-1}$?

b) How can T have an inverse matrix if T is not a square matrix? I tried the following commands in Matlab `syms t_1 t_2`, `T = [t_1 t_2]`, `T^(-1)`. This returned the error `Error using symengine. Not a square matrix.` 
The solutions says $\begin{bmatrix} k \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} $ Where did the $t_1$ go, when $T^{-1}x(0)$ was executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1: $\Lambda$ is enclosed by $T$ and $T^{-1}$ per the definition of [diagonalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix#Diagonalization).

Question 2: $t_1$ and $t_2$ are each $2 \times 1$ columns, so the resulting matrix $T$ is indeed square.

---

To your latest comment: they compute
$$
T \pmatrix{\frac{1}{s - \lambda_1}&0\\0& \frac{1}{s - \lambda_2}}(T^{-1}x(0)) = \\
k\;T \underbrace{\pmatrix{\frac{1}{s - \lambda_1}&0\\0& \frac{1}{s - \lambda_2}}\pmatrix{1\\0}} =\\
k T \pmatrix{\frac{1}{s - \lambda_1}\\0}
$$

Comment: Thank you for your help. So I understand that T actually has two column vectors. In a) we have found $\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{s-\lambda_1} & 0 \\ 0 & \frac{1}{s-\lambda_2} \end{bmatrix}$ in c) it is shortened to $\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{s-\lambda_1}  \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$, why? I would now have assumed $$ X(s) = \begin{bmatrix}k  \\ 0  \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}t_{1a} & t_{2a} \\ t_{1b} & t_{2b}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{s-\lambda_1} & 0 \\ 0 & \frac{1}{s-\lambda_2} \\ \end{bmatrix}$$ Is there anything special (as in "light bulb moment") about this exercise for a control engineer?

Comment: See my latest edit.  I'll get back to you on that "light bulb moment".

Comment: It is helpful to remember that $T$ represents a change of variables

Comment: Looking again at this exercise, I wonder how they get from $T^{-1}x(0)$ to $\begin{bmatrix} k \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$ I assume I am missing the steps in between.